# Swap переменных xor'ом в одно выражение

Tags: c++, c, неопределённое-поведение

Является ли такой способ обмена значений переменных неопределённым поведением?

http://codepad.org/3IFTpgwR

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int x = 10, y = 20;
  x ^= y ^= x ^= y;
  printf("%d %d", x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

Здесь есть двукратное присваивание переменной `x` - является ли оно некорректным?

PS: Вопрос возник из-за того, что другие языки иначе вычисляют эту конструкцию.

Comment: См. мой вопрос на английском [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315133/swap-integers-via-xor-in-single-line-is-it-really-allowed-in-c11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, является. Операция xor-c-присваиванием (^=) не является [точкой следования](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2005/11/sequence-points.html).

Многократное присваивание в рамках одной точки следования - UB.

Для обмена переменных в c++ есть `std::swap()`

Comment: А если это же записать тремя отдельными инструкциями? Если я правильно понял, то вопрос был о самом методе (обмен через xor), а не о том, как будет вычисляться конкретная конструкция x ^= y ^= x ^= y; Да и тут у меня определенные сомнения в непереносимости - ведь ^= является правоассоциативным, т.е. по стандарту это вычисление однозначно...

Comment: `точка следования` устаревшее название.

Comment: @alexolut, а новое тогда какое?

Comment: @Harry, нет, вопрос был именно о записи в один оператор. Запись в 2 оператора, очевидно, не является. В 3 - тоже.

Comment: @Harry - прочитайте пост, на который я в ответе ссылаюсь. Между двумя точками следования запрещено писать в переменную больше одного раза.

Comment: @gbg `sequenced before` (1.9/13)

Comment: @alexolut, уточню - "устаревшим" термин является в том смысле, что в C++11 начала появляться многопоточность, для которой набор соглашений был расширен. В рамках однопоточного выполнения все осталось прежним.

Comment: @gbg просто в `c++11` именно термина `sequence point` уже нет в Стандарте.

Comment: @gbg Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что, например,  код `x += y; y += x; x +=y;` является UB? Я же сформулировал вопрос - "А если это же записать тремя отдельными инструкциями?"

Comment: @Harry нет, в этом коде - три точки следования, разделенные ";" Прочитайте уже пост.

Comment: @gbg Я его уже читал - еще в первый раз :) Еще раз - сам принцип обмена через xor несет в себе какие-то подводные камни или нет?

Comment: @Harry - на это у меня есть другая статья - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98

Проблема xor-swap  в том, что он не всегда эффективен

Comment: @gbg Ага, спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: Предлагаю обновить ответ с учётом С++17. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616351/178988