# Какое значение примет элемент n[1] после выполнения команд:

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, неопределённое-поведение

```
int i = 0, n[] = {7, 5, 3, 1};
for ( ; i<3; n[i++] = n[i]);
```

Дело в том, что два разных компилятора (*Code Blocks* и *CppDroid*) выдают два разных значения. В Code Blocks получается `5`, а в CppDroid - `3`. Так какой же ответ правильный? Проблема в одном из компиляторов, или само задание некорректно?

Comment: 1) А что даёт расчёт на бумаге? 2) А что из приведеного является "выдают значение"?

Comment: например clang выдаёт такое сообщение `warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]` думаю это всё же UB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По-моему, порядок вычисления выражения слева и выражения справа при выполнении присваивания не оговорен стандартом (порядок определяется конкретным компилятором).

[Для C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf), раздел 5.17:

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. **In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression**. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation
>   of a compound assignment is a single evaluation

Поскольку итоговый результат вычисления зависит от порядка вычисления операндов, то и возникает undefined behavior.

Для [C++17](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ass), раздел 5.18, порядок вычисления уже более строго определен:

> The right operand is sequenced before the left operand.

Поэтому неопределенного поведения не должно возникать. И после выполнения цикла массив не изменится, поэтому `n[1]` равно 5.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!) То есть, конкретных правил определения значения первого элемента массива без использования компилятора в даном случае не существует? Просто это пример из экзаменационных заданий, и мне казалось, что там должны получаться однозначные ответы :))

Comment: По-моему, тут само задание составлено некорректно, либо его ответом является: неопределенное поведение.

Comment: Не понял, почему после _"The right operand is sequenced before the left operand"_ вычисление `i` по-прежнему unsequenced. Можно подробнее этот момент?

Comment: @Qwertiy, еще раз перечитал. Моя ошибка, неопределенного поведения в C++17 не должно возникнуть. Но могу ошибаться ибо дебри стандарта хорошо не знаю) надо протестировать

Comment: @Unknown, а в вашем задании не оговорено каким стандартом необходимо руководствоваться? С C++17 ответ должен быть однозначным - массив не изменится, `n[1]` равно 5

Comment: Нет, не оговорено. Но я приму это во внимание

Comment: @PavelParshin а вы уверены? Я тут собирал `-std=c++17` ответ 3. https://godbolt.org/g/rqkzqP Хотя в 7.0 уже ответ 5 но он в тестировании только.

Comment: @pavel Согласно спецификации GCC фича "Refining Expression Evaluation Order for Idiomatic C++"  была добавлена в GCC7. Собственно если переключиться на эту версию, то ответ 5.

Comment: @pavel https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z.html

Comment: @pavel что-то ссылка у Вас неправильная на godbolt.

Comment: Странно, что даже для GCC7 и `-std=c++1z` выводится [предупреждение](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/NRT7UxN3nKjtKSsh) о порядке вычислений.

Comment: @alexolut а что не так? у меня открывается...

Comment: @pavel сайт-то открывается, но код отображается локальный :) Т.е. я вижу свой код по Вашей ссылке. Там есть кнопка для шары спецовая.

Comment: @alexolut а это она и была... Проверил в другом браузере.

Comment: @pavel прикол. Хром открывает Ваш код, а FF мой :) Видимо глюки FF, ибо [вот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg5Jx.png).

Answer (score 6):

Компилятор *C++* имеет право переупорядочивать инструкции в целях оптимизации.

Рассмотрим  выражение

```
n[i++] = n[i]
```

Как оно может быть интерпретировано?

***Первый вариант.***

```
int tmp = i;
i = i + 1;
n[tmp] = n[i];
```

То есть, например, при `i == 0`

```
n[0] = n[1]
```

***Второй вариант***

```
auto tmp_n = n[i];
int tmp_i = i;
i = i + 1;
n[tmp_i] = tmp_n;
```

То есть, при `i == 0`

```
n[0] = n[0];
```

Таким образом, поскольку порядок вычислений внутри одной операции не определён, компилятор может сгенерировать как первый код, так и второй. То есть правильный ответ здесь следующий:

> Неопределено.

P.S. Кстати, *Code::Blocks* это не компилятор, а среда разработки, не имеющая собственного компилятора.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! :) А конкретных правил определения значения первого элемента массива без использования компилятора в данном случае не существует? Просто это пример из экзаменационных заданий, и мне казалось, что там должны получаться однозначные ответы :))

Comment: 1) Да, не существует. 2) Один и тот же компилятор может в разных ситуациях генерировать как первый вариант кода, так и второй. 3) Ответ однозначен - неопределённое поведение.

Comment: Я поняла. Ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Имеет место неопределенное поведение программы. Согласно стандарту C++ (1.9 Program execution)

> 15. ...If a side eﬀect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either 
>       another side eﬀect on the same scalar object or a value
>       computation using the value of the same scalar object, and they are
>       not potentially concurrent (1.10), the behavior is undeﬁned.

Там же в стандарте приведен схожий пример

```
i = i++ + 1; // the behavior is undeﬁned
```

Answer (score 2):

**Никакой**.

Фрагмент `n[i++] = n[i]` провоцирует **неопределённое поведение**, так как операция приравнивания не является [точкой следования](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2005/11/sequence-points.html).

Это значит, что оператор волен выбирать, какое именно выражение надо вычислять первее: `n[i++]` или `n[i]`. Единственное ограничение — к моменту присваивания оба фрагмента должны дать по значению (ссылку и число соответственно).

Неопределённое поведение следует из того, что компилятор рассматривает обе части *независимо*. Соответственно, `i++` из левой части и `i` из правой друг с другом как бы не связаны. Мало того, что *чтение-изменение-запись* постинкремента может быть переставлено местами с *просто чтением*, так они могут быть ещё и перемешаны друг с другом.

На большом StackOverflow уже был задан вопрос о том, [почему присваивание не является точкой следования](http:////stackoverflow.com/q/4362501/2553424):

> ***Имеется ли какое-нибудь обоснованию тому, что оператор `=` не является точкой следования как в Си, так и в C++?***
>
> Нужна веская причина для того, чтобы что-то **стало** точкой следования. В причинах же того, чтобы этого **не** делать, нужды нет — это вариант по умолчанию.
>
> К примеру, `&&` должен быть точкой следования из-за *short-circuiting*: если левая часть оператора ложна, правая его часть вычислена не будет. Это связано не столько с оптимизацией, сколько с возможностью создания зависимости правой части от левой (к примеру, в `ptr && ptr->data`). Поэтому левая часть обязательно должна быть вычислена строго до правой, чтобы знать, надо ли вычислять правую часть вообще.
>
> В случае же с `=` подобной причины не существует. Хотя этот оператор и является присваиванием (...), точный порядок вычисления сторон не имеет значения, пока они выполняются до собственно присваивания.

***P. S.*** Кстати, проблема с `++i + ++i` имеет такую же первопричину.

Comment: Только вот нет уже никаких точек следования в c++11 и выше.

Comment: @alexolut, 1) *6.5.16 «Assignment operators»*, пункт 3: `... The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.`  2) *6.5 «Expressions»*, пункт 2: `If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced ... the behavior is undefined.` Так что те же яйца, только в профиль и с дополнительным уровнем косвенности в придачу.

Answer (score 1):

Неопределенное поведение. Компилятор g++, запущенный с ключем `-Wall` честно предупреждает об этом.

Пример (с чуть модифицированной для печати промежуточных результатов программой):

```
avp@wubu:hashcode$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int i = 0, n[] = {7, 5, 3, 1};
  int l = 0;
  for ( ; i<3; n[i++] = n[i]) {
    printf("loop %d i = %d\n", l++, i);
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      printf("%d ", n[j]);
    puts("");
  }

  puts("");
  printf("result i = %d\n", i);
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    printf("%d ", n[j]);
  puts("");
}

avp@wubu:hashcode$ g++ -Wall t.c
t.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
t.c:11:28: warning: operation on ‘i’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
   for ( ; i<3; n[i++] = n[i]) {
                            ^
avp@wubu:hashcode$ ./a.out 
loop 0 i = 0
7 5 3 1 
loop 1 i = 1
5 5 3 1 
loop 2 i = 2
5 3 3 1 

result i = 3
5 3 1 1 
avp@wubu:hashcode$
```

Как видите `n[1] = 3`, т.е. этот компилятор в операторе присваивания (в данном случае это завершающая часть `for(;;)`) берет текущее значение `i`, вычисляет и запоминает адрес цели, увеличивает `i`, на основе уже нового значения `i` выбирает данные источника (`n[i]`) и копирует их по адресу цели.