# "С++" i = 5; i = ++i + ++i почему ответ 14? Как компилятор считает?

Tags: c++, c++11, инкремент

```
i = 5;
i = ++i + ++i
```

Как компилятор считает? Язык C++

Comment: Сначала ++i (6), потом ++i (7), затем сложение результатов (14). А вообще это [неопределенное поведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, 7+6=13

Comment: i перед сложением равно 7. 7+7=14

Comment: http://lurkmore.to/%2B%2Bi_%2B_%2B%2Bi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Результат вычисления

```
i = ++i + ++i
```

неопределен и может быть как 13, так и 14. Причиной неопределенного поведения в данном выражении является правило, по которому один и тот же объект между двумя точками следования не может быть изменен более одного раза. В выражении

```
i = ++i + ++i
```

операция **+** не является точкой следования и переменная **i** инкрементируется два раза. Компилятор по старшинству операций обязан сначала вычислить значения левого и правого операндов и только потом сложить их. Но при этом то, как он будет вычислять операнды неопределено. Поэтому компилятор может сначала инкрементировать переменную первый раз, потом инкрементировать переменную второй раз, затем подставить значение переменной в обе части сложения и получить 14. Но компилятор волен так же сначала инкрементировать переменную слева и подставить ее как первый операнд, затем инкрементировать переменную справа и подставить ее как второй операнд,потом сложить оба результата и получить 13.

Как правильно заметил **ixSci** в с++11 правило точки следования было заменено на правило отношения расположено-перед. Но смысл тот же: многократное изменение объекта в сочетании с чтением этого объекта - не упорядоченно.

Answer (score 4):

Результат вычисления выражения `++i + ++i`, как уже верно написали, может быть любым, т.к. это классический пример неопределенного поведения. Формально, компилятор имеет право выдать результат 42 с тем же успехом, как 12, 13 или 14. Может сформатировать диск или запустить ракеты.

Еще одно объяснение: `a + b` эквивалентно вызову функции `operator+(a, b)` (на самом деле не совсем, т.к. это верно не для любых операторов, об этом ниже) а порядок вычисления операндов функции не определен, это явно прописано в стандарте. Однако есть три бинарных оператора, порядок вычисления аргументов которых определен: это операторы `,` (запятая), `&&` и `||` (логические И и ИЛИ). Их операнды всегда вычисляются слева направо. То есть выражение

```
bool result = ++i && ++i;
```

не содержит UB (если i имеет встроенный тип). Также интересно, что если Вы перегружаете операторы `,`, `&&` и `||` для пользовательского класса, это поведение меняется, и порядок вычисления операндов становится неопределенным. Это причина того, что без крайней нужды эти операторы перегружать не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ может быть любым. Это классическая задачка на неопределенное поведение компилятора. Тут переменная изменяется 2 раза между точками следования

Comment: Небольшая придирка: в C++11 и дальше нет точек следования.

Comment: @ixSci, может напишете ответ в терминах С++11?

Comment: @ixSci, я уже [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616338/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-n1-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4/616376#comment852295_616376), что суть от этого не меняется.

Comment: @Arhad, я к _сути_ ответа вопросов и не имею.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, думаю, что стоит писать в терминах C++17, но я пока не готов писать такой ответ — имею только поверхностное знание последних изменений в этой части.