# Иные результаты работы с инкрементами

Tags: c++, инкремент

Только изучаю программирование и выбрал в качестве первого языка программирования С++. Во время изучения инкрементов решил немного поэксперементировать.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b;
    b = ++a + ++a + ++a;
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ожидал, что в качестве вывода получится 12 (т.к. насколько я понял, сначала переменные работают с инкрементами, а уже только после этого происходят другие операции), но почему - то выводится 10. Потом решил при присвоении переменной b взять 2 инкремента в скобки: b = ++a + (++a + ++a). Вывело 12. Хочу понять, почему так происходит (использовал CLion)

Comment: Классический пример неопределённого поведения. См.: [Понять где undefined behavour в арифметических выражениях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/679815).

Comment: Также см.: [i = 5; i = ++i + ++i почему ответ 14? Как компилятор считает?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726802)